# How do I get Selenium to always open application hyperlinks with the same app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm creating a program in Python using Selenium that interacts with Zoom.

If you've used Zoom before you'll know that you receive a meeting link that will open in your browser, then launch another link that prompts you to open it with Zoom (looks like `zoommtg:meetinginformation`)

What I would like to know is how can I configure Selenium so that it *always* knows to open `zoommtg:` link with Zoom (without always prompting "do you want to open this with zoom")?

#### For those that don't understand that, here's another example you might be more familiar with:

Generally you will download torrents via a `magnet:` link, which will then ask you to open your torrent client.

What I want to know is how can I get Selenium to always *automatically* open the app associated with the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved!

I [created a new Firefox Profile](https://www.guru99.com/firefox-profile-selenium-webdriver.html), and in it's settings, manually added Zoom as the default handler for `zoommtg:` links (this part is just done in the firefox settings).

I then loaded this profile into Selenium, like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('path/to/new/profile/')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
```

And, obviously, this will work for all other application-specific links.

Comment: +1 I think it's worth noting that the article you provided at the start of your answer is only useful in creating a Firefox profile if you're using *Selenium Python*. The instructions after that only show how to use the profile in Selenium for *Java*. But at least you provided an example of how to do the same in Python!